lazyUpdate change the token in the headers authorization (Angular 17)
I've encountered this problem that the lazyUpdate in the headers of a call change and update my authorization token and for that reason the endpoint returns me the error 403 Forbidden.
In my Angular application I fetch a token and an endpoint from a server and I should use these two parameters to make a GET call to the endpoint in order to receive data inside the application.
The steps are:

fetch the endpoint and the token from an http-server
make a GET call to the endpoint with headers({'Authorization': token}) (the token doesn't have the Bearer prefix because the token that the server returns to me isn't a Bearer; and if I put the prefix Bearer the endpoint returns error 403)
during the call the lazyInit set the correct value of the token but then the lazyUpdate change the token in a Bearer token and for that reason the endpoint returns 403 Forbidden.

Is it possible that the problem is related to the HttpInterceptors?
Is it possible to remove the lazyUpdate or set it equals to the lazyInit?
I'm trying to fix this problem by using the HttpInterceptors. Specifically I created an if that checks if the token contains or doesn't contain the prefix Bearer. In the case !isBearerPresent I set the authorization token with the one received by the server, unfortunately the lazyUpdate keeps updating the token.
Solution of the problem:
The problem is related to Keycloak in angular. I fixed it by adding the URL (where I don't want to update the token in the lazyUpdate) inside the function of the initiaization of Keycloak in angular.
export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService):(auth:KeycloakService, environment: AppConfigService)=> Promise<any>{
    const options: KeycloakOptions = {
        config: {
            url: environment.authURL,
            realm: environment.realm,
            clientId: environment.clientId,

        },loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false,
        initOptions:{
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            checkLoginIframe: true,
        },
        bearerExcludedUrls:[
            //add URLs you don't want the token to be updated in lazyUpdate
            environment.Url,
        ],
    }
    return (): Promise<any>=> keycloak.init(options);

}

